# How can i use data which has bigger size than RAM memory?

Tags: python, memory

I want to search string S is in category. And category file is saved in folder.
I want to load category file and search S, but size of category file exceed size of RAM memory. So i cant load category file. In this case, how can i know string S is in category or not?

Comment: You could use a database. An easy way to do that is to use the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module in Python's standard library.

Comment: By not loading the whole file in the memory?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to process your big file one line at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

N = 0
with open('BigFile.txt', 'r') as f:
   while True:
      line = f.readline()
      if not line:
          print('No cats found')
          break
      if 'cat' in line:
          print(f'Found cat, on line {N}')
          break
      N += 1
```

Create a test file with 3 million lines like this, with the word "cat" on the final line like this:

```
jot -w "%08d" 3000000 > BigFile.txt
echo cat >> BigFile.txt
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `mmap()` and let your operating system do the work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import mmap
import re

# Open file and mmap it into memory to search in it for "cat"
with open('BigBoy', 'r') as f:
    with mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as m:
        match = re.search(b'cat', m)
        if match:
            print(f'Found {match.re.pattern} at offset {match.start()}')
```

---

**Example**:

First, make a file too big for RAM, e.g. 64GB with the word "cat" at the end:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=BigBoy bs=1G count=64
echo cat >> BigBoy
```

Now search in file bigger than RAM:

```
./SearchInMmapFile.py                        
Found b'cat' at offset 68719476736
```