# Sharing a large file between processes in multiprocessing.pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to find a match for a randomly generated public key in a large database. Since the process generates private and public keys for every search attempt, it's resource intensive and I want to speed it up with multiprocessing.pool

Example structure:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

large_file = open("database.txt", "r")
large_db = large_file.read()
large_file.close()


def search(process_id):
    while True:
        search_term = os.urandom(32).decode('latin1') # This is just a placeholder, the actual program would generate key pairs
        if search_term in large_db:
            print(f"[{process_id}] match: {search_term}")

with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
    pool.map(search, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This would work, but the database would be copied for every process, which isn't feasible if it's multiple gigabytes in size. Is there a way to share the database that's loaded in memory with all the process in the pool?

Comment: Each sub-process runs in its own address space. You should just get each sub-process to open and read the file. Depending on its internal structure you could potentially reduce memory requirements by reading one line at a time. You could share the file contents with shared memory if you're familiar with the multiprocessing.shared_memory module

Comment: I have attempted using shared_memory, but most sources online only talk about numpy arrays, whereas I simply need to share a large string. Using those guides and swapping out for my file data results in the error "TypeError: memoryview: invalid type for format 'B'". This happens even if the data is encoded to bytes.

Comment: Is database.txt line-oriented?

Comment: yup, it's a txt file with single line public keys

Comment: You would need to think about where the bulk of the time is spent. How long does it take to generate the keypairs vs how it takes to search for them - then decide which aspect to optimise. It may be that the way you store the data (in say, a set, for example) allows faster checking for membership or presence in the set. It may be an idea, if the searching is slow, to enlist a couple of inexpensive PCs running Redis and to round-robin lookups between them since the data needed to be transferred for a lookup is minimal.

Comment: There are probably many better ways to do this yes, but I would like to learn more about sharing memory between processes in a pool. Is it really that difficult to share read-only file data between processes?

Comment: You can just `mmap()` the same file (read-only) from multiple processes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74595751/2836621 Make sure you anchor your search at, say, start of line, to make it fast.

Comment: "This would work, but the database would be copied for every process, which isn't feasible if it's multiple gigabytes in size." is not true if you're on POSIX (Linux, macOS, ...) and using `fork` as your multiprocessing spawn method. In fact, your example code would be pretty optimal for that scenario.

Comment: Testing membership in a `set` should be miles faster though. So maybe have one process that creates an in-memory set, and holds it in memory, then let the others submit keypairs to it (via multiprocessing queues maybe) for testing.

Comment: Honestly, though, I'd probably stuff the data in a SQLite database (in an indexed column, of course, maybe hashed if you like) and just query it from the multiple processes.

Comment: Your program as written never terminates because `search` contains an infinite loop that never terminates. So it's not clear how this code is to be re-structured. Are you missing a `break` statement in that infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could use shared memory.

The code in the original question is incomplete although the intent is clear.

In the following code (which will need to be adapted for your specific needs) we have a file that contains >82,000 lines. On each line there is a single word.

There are two discrete approaches. One where we deal with line-oriented data and another where we just have a single "blob" of text.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from itertools import repeat
from random import choice

FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/ukenglish.txt'
PROCS = 10
WORDS = [
    'banana',
    'grapefruit',
    'orange',
    'lemon',
    'pancake',
    'foofarb',
    'performance',
    'sausage',
    'pork',
    'beef',
    'chicken'
]

# The searches take a word at random from the global WORDS list
# and then either search a ShareableList (search1)or a shared memory buffer (search2)

def search1(sl):
    response = 'Found' if (word := choice(WORDS)) in sl else 'Could not find'
    print(f'{response} {word}')

def search2(sm):
    buffer = bytes(sm.buf).decode()
    response = 'Found' if (word := choice(WORDS)) in buffer else 'Could not find'
    print(f'{response} {word}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        # handle line-oriented data by using a ShareableList
        with open(FILENAME, 'rt') as db:
            sl = smm.ShareableList([line.strip() for line in db.readlines()])
            with Pool() as pool:
                pool.map(search1, repeat(sl, PROCS))
        print('---------------')
        # handle a "blob" by creating a single shared memory buffer
        with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as db:
            ld = len(data := db.read())
            sm = smm.SharedMemory(ld)
            sm.buf[:ld] = data
            with Pool() as pool:
                pool.map(search2, repeat(sm, PROCS))
```